# Which airports serve only international destinations?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, where-on-earth, factoids

In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152137/which-airport-has-direct-flights-to-the-most-countries), concerning the airports that serve the *most* countries, domestic flights are excluded (i.e. the country containing the airport should not contribute to its destination count).

This leads me to wonder - are there any examples of airports where this wouldn't make a difference to the score, as they don't have any domestic flights?

An obvious case would be countries that are simply too small to have more than one airport; those qualify, but should probably be noted as such. More interesting would be countries with multiple airports, at least one of which for some reason lacks domestic services.

As to which flights count, same rules as the original:

> Flights must be regularly scheduled, although they can be seasonal,
>   and available to book for individual passengers, to exclude chartering
>   an airline and private flights.

Comment: I have the feeling that asking for the country which has the most of such airports would make the question more interesting.

Comment: One more country, the Netherlands, as far as I can see no domestic flights anymore.

Comment: @Willeke Wouldn't flights to the Dutch Antilles count as domestic?

Comment: I would not count them as domestic but I am not yet used to the current legal status. For me the Netherlands is still the main European lump with the islands that are very close to it, not its former colonies halfway across the world.

Comment: The UK and France also probably have more than a few such airports by virtue of having overseas possessions.

Comment: Closing as there's at least a dozen such airports just off the top of my head. Please make the criteria more narrow.

Comment: This is too easy. Any country with only one passenger airport would qualify, and there are dozens of those, from Bhutan to Helena.

Comment: All [city-states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City-state) + a few more.

Answer (score 8):

You will have plenty of examples. Any country big (or populous) enough for more than one airport, but small enough so that domestic flights make no sense will be fine.

Just one example: Belgium.

There are five airports with regular passenger flights: [Brussels](https://www.brusselsairport.be), [Charleroi](https://www.brussels-charleroi-airport.com), [Ostend](https://www.luchthaven-oostendebrugge.com/), [Antwerp](https://www.luchthaven-antwerpen.com/) and [Liège](https://www.liegeairport.com). Non of them offer domestic flights. Simply because it makes no sense at all. Just take the train and it will be faster and more convenient.

Comment: Similarly there are US states with multiple airports but no intrastate flights, for example Tennessee (there are five airports with regular flights, Memphis, Nashville, Chattanooga, Knoxville, and Bristol, but no flights among them).  Here it helps that no airline currently has a hub at any of these airports - just to the south, Georgia *does* have interstate flights, between its various outlying airports and Atlanta.

Answer (score 2):

The country can still be small enough that domestic flights between the airports don't make sense. An example would be Cyprus, which has two international airports: [Larnaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larnaca_International_Airport) and [Paphos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paphos_International_Airport) with no flights between them.

Answer (score 2):

Singapore has two civilian Airports - Changi and Seletar airport.

Both serves international destinations only.